# apt not installing package, even though it exists on the source

Tags: apt, raspbian

I'm having a problem with some old packages installed on my machines. 
Some of those packages are very old and insecure. 
However, apt-get install doesn't recognize new versions, and even when providing a version number, it says that version can't be found (although I can see it when manually browsing to the source).

It should be noted that I am using a device called "RevolutionPi", a variation of a Raspberry Pi.

an example of a package could be python-apt which on my device is currently version 1.1.0:

my sources.list:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

The steps I did:

1. Burn a stretch-lite version of Raspbian.
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get install` (for example, `python-apt=1.4.1`)

the result: 'version 1.4.1 for python-apt was not found.'

My questions:

1. Why is that happening? Does the apt decide if a package is compatible for my system or applies some other similar logic?
2. Is it problematic if I download the deb file and manually install it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-get update`?

Comment: run `apt-get policy python-apt` to know the exact version available. raspbian might differ from debian. in http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages I have Package: python-apt Version: 1.1.0~beta5

Comment: so looks to me all is behaving as expected. Except the raspbian repository hasn't been updated like would be the real debian repository

Comment: `apt-cache policy python-apt` will assist when troubleshooting the preferences.

Comment: Thank you all. The case was indeed debian having more recent packages than Raspbian. 
So another question arises: python-apt 1.1.0~beta5 has known vulnerabilities. If I would like to upgrade it (and other unsafe pacakges), but still maintain the Raspbian kernel (or more specifically the RevolutionPi custom kernel), would the following steps be correct? : 
1. Burn clean Raspbian stretch. 
2. Add Debian "security" source.
3. apt-mark hold raspberrypi-kernel.
4. apt-get update
5. apt-get upgrade
6. remove the Debian source
?